# Extract contents of a list

Tags: python

I have two lists and b. I want to extract the items that are similar and dissimilar. The thing is a[i] is inside b[i] e.g a[0] == b[0:3]. My attempted solution here gets the similar ones (in the else statement) but not the dissimilar ones (if statement). The if statement creates multiple inputs, kindly point me to what I am missing.

```
a = [[1,2,3], [9,8,3], [1,3,5], [2,3,8], [0,3,5], [5,5,7]]
b = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [4,5,6,8,6,0], [9,8,3,7,8,9], [5,5,7,0,3,9]]

temp, temp1 = [], []
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        if i != j[0:3]:
            temp.append(j)
        else:
            temp1.append(j)

#print temp should output [[1,3,5], [2,3,8], [0,3,5]] but it gives something different

#print temp1 [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [9, 8, 3, 7, 8, 9], [5, 5, 7, 0, 3, 9]] is fine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nesting of loops makes the if condition to be executed on all possible combinations of ai and bj. Moreover, from what you mentioned in your requirement, you seem to be needing values of ai in temp (not bj)

You can use a boolean variable to hold found/not found boolean value, as shown:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [9,8,3], [1,3,5], [2,3,8], [0,3,5], [5,5,7]]
b = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [4,5,6,8,6,0], [9,8,3,7,8,9], [5,5,7,0,3,9]]

temp, temp1 = [], []
for i in a:
    found = False
    for j in b:
        if i != j[0:3]:
            pass
        else:
            found = True
            temp1.append(j)
    if not found :
        temp.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [[1,2,3], [9,8,3], [1,3,5], [2,3,8], [0,3,5], [5,5,7]]
b = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [4,5,6,8,6,0], [9,8,3,7,8,9], [5,5,7,0,3,9]]

temp, temp1 = [], []
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        if i != j[0:3]:
            **temp.append(i)
            break**
        else:
            temp1.append(j)
```